# Check the OpenAfterPublish box without exporting a PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf-generation

I can use the following code to export sheet to PDF file without publishing. But I like to turn back on `OpenAfterPublish` after my export using my code.

```
    Sheet1.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                fileName:="C:\pdf.pdf", _
                                Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
                                IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
                                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

I tried to search around for where Excel store the registries. But nothing can be found.

I also search for a workaround, e.g. export nothing and pass `OpenAfterPublish:=True`.

Is there a way to set `OpenAfterPublish:=True` as default without further export.

Comment: Why would you do that? You can just set it everytime you use `.ExportAsFixedFormat`.

Comment: I need the PDF pop up when user export by hand. And I need excel export silently when user run the code. It is about better user experience.